# SBT ProGuard plugin: OutOfMemoryError, how to increase heapspace?

Tags: scala, sbt, proguard, out-of-memory

When trying to assemble a jar for my project with the sbt-proguard plugin, I invariably get an `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

I tried increasing the heap space for sbt, but it turns out the proguard plugin spawns its own java process and has the `-Xmx256M` parameter hardcoded. I can't figure out how to change it, short of changing the proguard code itself.

I am using sbt-proguard plugin 0.2.1 with sbt 0.12.3 and Scala 2.10.1 on JDK 7

I have tried the setting `javaOptions in proguard := Seq("-Xmx2G")` as well as `javaOptions in proguard += "-Xmx2G"`,  but the plugin seems to ignore/overwrite this:

```
> ps aux|grep java
kaeser         47084 105.1  1.1  2927540  94440 s000  R+   10:07AM   0:05.52 /usr/bin/java -Xmx256M -cp /Users/kaeser/.ivy2/cache/net.sf.proguard/proguard-base/jars/proguard-base-4.9.jar proguard.ProGuard -include /Users/kaeser/Documents/workspace/pipeline-runner/target/scala-2.10/proguard/configuration.pro
kaeser         45087   0.0  6.3  5312012 531028 s000  S+    6:03PM   1:24.88 /usr/bin/java -Xmx2G -Xms512M -Xmx2G -Xss1M -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Xshare:off -jar /usr/local/Cellar/sbt/0.12.3/libexec/sbt-launch.jar
```

How might I pass Java options to the proguard plugin, or otherwise solve this issue?

Answer (score 9):

add `javaOptions in proguard := Seq("-Xmx...")` line to your project settings

**Updated**

Ok i guess i know what your problem is.
If you print in sbt session the following command:

```
show proguard::java-options
```

it will print you `[info] List(-Xmx2G)`, this means that in you proguard `configuration` heap size is set to `2GB`, but if you try this command: `show proguard:proguard::java-options` it will show you `[info] List(-Xmx256M)` which is used in the proguardTask. Taking this in consideration i'm guessing that you have something like this in you project settings:

```
 lazy val main = Project(
    id = "project",
    base = file("."),
    settings = Seq(javaOptions in proguard := Seq("-Xmx2G")) ++ proguardSettings)
```

Basicly what is happening, proguardSettigns using default configuration and erases your javaOptions settings with the fact that task is using task scope for the command.

So add this line:

```
javaOptions in (SbtProguard.Proguard, proguard) := Seq("-Xmx2G")
```

to your settings, it should looks similar to this:

```
lazy val main = Project(
  id = "project",
  base = file("."),
  settings =  proguardSettings ++ Seq(
    javaOptions in (SbtProguard.Proguard, proguard) := Seq("-Xmx2G")
  )
```

and now call `show proguard:proguard::java-options` it will show you `[info] List(-Xmx2G)`. You can also turn on global logging for the session and see if everything is ok: `set logLevel in Global := Level.Debug`

**Update**

I prefer `Build.scala` files, but in `*.sbt` it's simpler, just add this lines in this order:

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtProguard._
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtProguard.ProguardKeys.proguard

proguardSettings

javaOptions in (Proguard, proguard) := Seq("-Xmx2G")
```

preserving the order and linebreak between the lines

Comment: I have tried that, and variations, but the plugin seems to ignore the setting.

Comment: @JustinKaeser try to increase `-XX:MaxPermSize=1G`

Comment: Okay, I tried it, but since perm size wasn't the issue, the problem persists.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid I don't quite follow. I don't have a setup as you describe, just a regular build.sbt with

Comment: Sorry, I sent that comment to early. It was meant to say:

Thanks, but I'm afraid I don't quite follow. I don't have a setup as you describe, just a regular build.sbt with
`import ProguardKeys._` and `proguardSettings`.

Adding the line you suggest in build.sbt just gives an error: `error: not found: value SbtProguard`

Comment: @JustinKaeser because you need to import them into `*.sbt` file. Check update with imports

Comment: Thanks, but even with the additional imports it still yields the same error :(

Answer (score 6):

The above answer was not working for me with more recent SBT/sbt-proguard.

With the recent [sbt-proguard](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-proguard) plugin and SBT 0.13.1, I have been able to get the following to work:

```
name := "project"

organization := "scott.andy"

version := "0.0.0"

scalacOptions := Seq("-deprecation", "-unchecked")

proguardSettings

ProguardKeys.options in Proguard ++= Seq("-dontnote", "-dontwarn", "-ignorewarnings")

ProguardKeys.options in Proguard += ProguardOptions.keepMain("scott.andy.project.Main")

inConfig(Proguard)(javaOptions in ProguardKeys.proguard := Seq("-Xmx2g"))
```

Comment: `Proguard/proguard/javaOptions := Seq("-Xmx4g")` worked for me